# Finding a column vector that spans the line defined by these two following equations.

Tags: calculus

$x+2y+2z=0$

$x+5y+4z=0$

This is the only homework question I am stuck on. How can two planes define a line? Is it the intersection of the planes?

I would really appreciate a concrete answer, thank you in advance.

Comment: Almost all the answers are partial. You need to show that the direction of the line which is given by the intersection of these two planes is a multiple of the vector $n_1 \times n_2$ where $n_i$ represent the normal vector of each plane respectively.  You can't just assume this, which is what a lot of users are doing. To do this, you must find two points in the intersection say $p,q$ and so $p-q = \lambda( n_1 \times n_2)$. Now we can assert that one parametrization of the line is $p+t(n_1 \times n_2)$ of $q + t(n_1 \times n_2)$.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Come on! It is MY answer this one and just ONE point and the direction vector is needed to define the line...

Comment: @Raffaele: You know that the cross product of those two normals gives the direction of the line because of the comment I made. So even if not worked out, I would just state it. The problem with calc III is that the details in most situations are "too high level"... sometimes. So when they are not, like in this case, things should be mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two planes intersect along a straight line, if they are not parallel.

The line is perpendicular to both the normal vectors defining the two planes, i.e. it is parallel to their cross product.

In this case plane $p_1:x+2y+2z=0$ has a normal vector $\vec n_1=(1,2,2)$

while plane $p_2:x+5y+4z=0$ has normal vector $vec n_2=(1,5,4)$

$\vec v=\vec n_1 \times \vec n_2=(-2,-2,3)$

All we need now is a point common to the two planes that is clearly the origin $O(0,0,0)$

Therefore the line has parametric equations $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)+t\vec v$

or $x=-2t;\;y=-2t;\;z=3t$

The vector you are looking for is $\vec v=(-2,\;-2,\;3)$

Answer (score 2):

It's the intersection of these planes that generates a line. You can find such an intersection by solving the system of equations
$$\begin{cases}x+2y+2z=0\\x+5y+4z=0\end{cases}$$
Which corresponds to the matrix equation
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&2\\1&5&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
which can be solved by using elementary row operations on the coefficient matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{l}(a,b,c)$ be a needed vector.

Hence, $(a,b,c)\perp(1,2,2)$ and $(a,b,c)\perp(1,5,4)$.

Thus, $$a+2b+2c=0$$ and
$$a+5b+4c=0.$$
I hope the rest is smooth.

I got that we can assume $$\vec{l}(2,2,-3)$$ and since $(0,0,0)$ is a common point, we got
$$(2t,2t,-3t)$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are talking about the intersection of the two planes. In general, if you have to surfaces (which could be planes, but also spheres, paraboloids or others) each defined by some equation, then the intersection of the surfaces is defined by the two equations simultaneously.

A vector defining a line which lies in both planes would be orthogonal to both $(1,2,2)$ and $(1,5,4)$. Thus you can get one such vector by using the vector cross product on those two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

For some intuitive understanding

1. How can 2 planes define a line?

By intersecting. Imagine an open book. The left hand page is (part of ) one plane and the right hand page is (part of) another plane. They intersect in the line where the pages are bound together. (There is a special case of the "2" planes being identical in which case the intersection is not a line but the whold plane.)

2. To find the direction of the line

Solve the simultaneous equations (as shown in other answers). This is because the points on the line simultaneously belong to both planes. There are 3 unknowns but only 2 equations so you get many answers, but they are all parallel and give the direction of the line.